# How to clear screen in erlang shell for win11?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I want to clear the screeen in erlang shell in win11.
When using powershell, I found it seems only possible to clear screen is to exit erlang shell, then to use ctrl-L for clear.

But it is not what I want. I need to clear erlang screen output without interrupt the running program.

It is workable in macOS. Is it possible in win11?